# Implementing a generic API caller

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to implement a generic caller that uses OpenWeatherMap's different weather API's, but I got stuck in regards to how I would put in the right identifier for the link.

- **.../weather?q=...** returns JSON data for the current weather;
- **.../forecast?q=...** returns JSON data for a five day forecast.

I am looking for the textbook way to maybe retrieve the API type of each class through accessing `GetAPIType()`, cast that to an int and put it in the index, so that I would be able to use `identifiers[index]`. Or perhaps there is an easier way to do it.

Checking for the `typeof(T)` also crossed my mind, and I would assign the index depending on the `if(typeof(T).Equals(typeof(...)))` construct, but that seems very messy and if OpenWeatherMap had 100 API's in theory, I would need 100 different if constructs. With this in mind, wouldn't creating those checks beat the purpose of Client being generic?

A third solution I thought of would be passing `APIType type` as a parameter for the Client constructor,

e.g. `var client = new Client<CurrentWeatherDTO>(APIType.CurrentWeather, location, apiKey)`,

but given the fact that Client is generic and I already provide a type when I instantiate it, it would seem awfully redundant.

**Client.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Rainy.OpenWeatherMapAPI
{
    public class Client<T>
    {
        private readonly string location;
        private readonly string apiKey;
        private readonly string requestUri;
        private readonly string[] identifiers = { "weather", "forecast" };
        private readonly int index;

        public Client(string location, string apiKey)
        {
            // Get the type of API used in order to get the right identifier for the link.
            // ??? Maybe use Reflection, somehow.
            this.location = location;
            this.apiKey = apiKey;
            requestUri = $"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/{}?q={location}&appid={apiKey}";
        }

        public async Task<T> GetWeather(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken))
            {
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return DeserializeJsonFromStream<T>(stream);

                var content = await StreamToStringAsync(stream);
                throw new APIException
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                    Content = content
                };
            }
        }

        private U DeserializeJsonFromStream<U>(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream == null || stream.CanRead == false)
                return default(U);

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var js = new JsonSerializer();
                var searchResult = js.Deserialize<U>(jtr);
                return searchResult;
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> StreamToStringAsync(Stream stream)
        {
            string content = null;

            if (stream != null)
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

**APIType.cs**

```
namespace Rainy.OpenWeatherMapAPI
{
    public enum APIType
    {
        CurrentWeather = 0,
        FiveDayForecast = 1
    }
}
```

**IWeather.cs**

```
namespace Rainy.OpenWeatherMapAPI
{
    public interface IWeather
    {
        APIType GetAPIType();
    }
}
```

**CurrentWeatherDTO.cs**

```
namespace Rainy.OpenWeatherMapAPI.CurrentWeatherData
{
    class CurrentWeatherDTO : IWeather
    {
        public APIType GetAPIType()
        {
            return APIType.CurrentWeather;
        }
    }
}
```

**FiveDayForecastDTO.cs**

```
namespace Rainy.OpenWeatherMapAPI.WeatherForecastData
{
    class FiveDayForecastDTO : IWeather
    {
        public APIType GetAPIType()
        {
            return APIType.FiveDayForecast;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use an enum to drive the index of an array.

I would directly return the string in a static way.

This solution can also work with the index of the array if you want.

Here is the code and the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AVCjSH):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client1 = new Client<CurrentWeatherDTO>(null);
        Console.WriteLine("Client CurrentWeather type: " + client1.Type);

        var client2 = new Client<FiveDayForecastDTO>(null);
        Console.WriteLine("Client FiveDay type: " + client2.Type);
    }

    public class Client<T> where T : IWeather, new()
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Client(string apiKey)
        {
            var dto = (IWeather)new T();
            this.Type = dto.GetAPIType();
        }
    }

    public static class APIType
    {
        public static string CurrentWeather = "weather";
        public static string FiveDayForecast = "forecast";
    }

    public interface IWeather
    {
        string GetAPIType();
    }

    class CurrentWeatherDTO : IWeather
    {
        public string GetAPIType()
        {
            return APIType.CurrentWeather;
        }
    }

    class FiveDayForecastDTO : IWeather
    {
        public string GetAPIType()
        {
            return APIType.FiveDayForecast;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply brilliant, I never thought of making an instance of T and just calling the method. Also, you might be right with not using an Enum for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a solution like this, but maybe a bit more error handling.

There's a couple of references for how to use HttpClient.

I don't really understand the part in the requestUri with `{}`, maybe that's part of your problem, I changed it to `{???}` in my sample code.

```
class Client
{
    // Problems using HttpClient and look into using IHttpClientFactory...
    // http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html
    // https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpClientFactoryForTypedHttpClientInstancesInASPNETCore21.aspx
    static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    readonly string WeatherUri = $"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/{???}?q={0}&appid={1}";
    public async Task<T> GetWeather<T>(string location, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var apiKey = ApiKeyAttribute.GetApiKey<T>();
        if (apiKey == null) throw new Exception("ApiKeyAttirbute missing");
        var requestUri = string.Format(WeatherUri, location, apiKey);
        return await GetItem<T>(requestUri, cancellationToken);
    }
    public async Task<T> GetItem<T>(string requestUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, cancellationToken);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new Exception("Error requesting data");
        if (response.Content == null) return default(T);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
    }
}
[ApiKeyAttribute("weather")]
class CurrentWeatherDTO { /* add appropriat properties */ }
[ApiKeyAttribute("forecast")]
class FiveDayForecastDTO { /* add appropriat properties */ }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
class ApiKeyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ApiKeyAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public static string GetApiKey<T>()
    {
        var attribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<ApiKeyAttribute>();
        return attribute?.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, the `{}` in my code was supposed to hold the identifier for the link, this is why I left it blank, since I didn't know how I would retrieve it. So it was on purpose. The second `{}` is for the location I query for and the third `{}` is the for apiKey. All in all, I think I can also use this approach to retrieve my identifier.

Comment: @Marek that's alright then, I just wanted to point it out in case it was something you had missed. Cheers